# How to apply a custom function and quote the grouped data itself by dplyr::summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to apply a customed function to summarise() in dplyr and in the fuction the grouped data itself should be quoted.

Here goes an example:

What I have:

Here comes the subset of a data set acquire by microplate reader and I want to calculate the alteration velocity of every well.

```
> data.05<- subset(data.kin.mlt, sample==5 & time<60)
> data.05
```

```
    position sample sample_class RESULT time     OD
5        A05      5        \tSMP  3.998    0 0.0696
17       B05      5        \tSMP 23.413    0 0.6176
29       C05      5        \tSMP  9.853    0 0.5146
41       D05      5        \tSMP  4.975    0 0.0516
53       E05      5        \tSMP  4.618    0 0.0496
65       F05      5        \tSMP  4.954    0 0.0556
77       G05      5        \tSMP  4.065    0 0.0546
101      A05      5        \tSMP  3.998   15 0.0696
113      B05      5        \tSMP 23.413   15 0.5126
125      C05      5        \tSMP  9.853   15 0.6116
137      D05      5        \tSMP  4.975   15 0.0516
149      E05      5        \tSMP  4.618   15 0.0506
161      F05      5        \tSMP  4.954   15 0.0566
173      G05      5        \tSMP  4.065   15 0.0556
197      A05      5        \tSMP  3.998   30 0.0710
209      B05      5        \tSMP 23.413   30 0.4340
221      C05      5        \tSMP  9.853   30 0.6150
233      D05      5        \tSMP  4.975   30 0.0520
245      E05      5        \tSMP  4.618   30 0.0510
257      F05      5        \tSMP  4.954   30 0.0580
269      G05      5        \tSMP  4.065   30 0.0560
293      A05      5        \tSMP  3.998   45 0.0710
305      B05      5        \tSMP 23.413   45 0.6010
317      C05      5        \tSMP  9.853   45 0.6190
329      D05      5        \tSMP  4.975   45 0.0540
341      E05      5        \tSMP  4.618   45 0.0520
353      F05      5        \tSMP  4.954   45 0.0590
365      G05      5        \tSMP  4.065   45 0.0570


> str(data.05)
'data.frame':   28 obs. of  6 variables:
 position    : Factor w/ 7 levels "A05","B05","C05",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 ...
 sample      : Factor w/ 12 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 sample_class: Factor w/ 2 levels "\tBLK","\tSMP": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 RESULT      : num  4 23.41 9.85 4.97 4.62 ...
 time        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 15 15 15 ...
 OD          : num  0.0696 0.6176 0.5146 0.0516 0.0496 ...
```

Now I can fulfill the purpose to calculate the slop by an ugly way:

```
> function.lm function.lm(subset(data.05, position=="A05"))
> function.lm(subset(data.05, position=="A05"))
        time 
3.733333e-05 
> function.lm(subset(data.05, position=="B05"))
     time 
-0.000856 
> function.lm(subset(data.05, position=="C05"))
       time 
0.002110667 
> function.lm(subset(data.05, position=="D05"))
        time 
5.066667e-05 
> function.lm(subset(data.05, position=="E05"))
        time 
5.066667e-05 
> function.lm(subset(data.05, position=="F05"))
        time 
7.733333e-05 
> function.lm(subset(data.05, position=="G05"))
        time 
5.066667e-05
```

But I'm looking for a pretty way, so

What I did:

```
> summarise(group_by(data.05, position), function.lm(data.05))
# A tibble: 7 × 2
  position `function.lm(data.05)`
                      
1      A05           0.0002173333
2      B05           0.0002173333
3      C05           0.0002173333
4      D05           0.0002173333
5      E05           0.0002173333
6      F05           0.0002173333
7      G05           0.0002173333
```

What I expected:

```
> summarise(group_by(data.05, position), function.lm(data.05))
# A tibble: 7 × 2
  position `function.lm(data.05)`
                      
1      A05           3.733333e-05 
2      B05              -0.000856 
3      C05            0.002110667 
4      D05           5.066667e-05 
5      E05           5.066667e-05 
6      F05           7.733333e-05 
7      G05           5.066667e-05
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `summarise` to `do` should work, if `function.lm` returns a data frame:

```
do(group_by(data.05, position), function.lm(.))
```

Or you need to construct a data frame from the return:

```
do(group_by(data.05, position), data.frame(time = unname(function.lm(.))))
```

Comment: I have tried this code but the result showed "Error: Results are not data frames at positions: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7". Maybe something is wrong with my data, hence the original question was updated with the structure of the data.

Comment: Can you check what `function.lm` return? i.e. what is `class(function.lm(subset(data.05, position=="E05")))`.

Comment: `function.lm` should return a data frame, if it's not you can try this `do(group_by(data.05, position), data.frame(time = function.lm(.)))`

Comment: The result of `function.lm` was `unction(x)coefficients(lm(OD~time, x))[2]` and the result of  `class(function.lm(subset(data.05, position=="E05")))` is `[1] "numeric"`